# is it possible/good to have two helper class for one controller and view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

i have too many functions that needs to be used in my view, and my helper class is looking too long. so is it possible/good to have two helper class for a single controller and view?

if so how to define the second helper class?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new helper:

1. choose a name for the helper file, for instance my_helper.rb
2. create the file in the /app/helpers directory
3. create a module according to the file name. In this case

   ```
   module MyHelper
   end
   ```
4. define your helper as method

   ```
   module MyHelper
     def hello_world(name)
       "hello #{name}"
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Step 5 is not needed

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
rails new example_app
cd example_app/
rails g scaffold Page title:string
rake db:migrate
rails s -p 3001
```

now create 2 helpers:

```
touch ./app/helpers/a_helper.rb
touch ./app/helpers/b_helper.rb
```

now put the following modules in their respective file.

```
module AHelper
  def same_method_name
    "Hi from AHelper"
  end
end

module BHelper
  def same_method_name
    "Hi from BHelper"
  end
end
```

now inside `./app/views/pages/index.html.erb` put this helper method somewhere.

```
<%= same_method_name %>
```

and visit `localhost:3001/pages`

You will see `Hi from BHelper` rendered in the page.

All helper modules, are included in your views and will override each other depending on the order they get included.

Now try this:

```
module BHelper
  def same_method_name
    "Hi from BHelper #{super}"
  end
end
```

`super` will keep going up the inheritance chain, to the next method called `same_method_name` and that method is `AHelper`'s `#same_method_name` so you will get `"Hi from BHelper Hi from AHelper"`

Rails helpers are good if want a quick and simple solution but if need more encapsulation consider using the decorator pattern (using a gem like Draper for example).